# Save uploaded file at nextjs custom server

Tags: node.js, file-upload, next.js, antd

I used the antDesign file upload component in one form. After the file is fully uploaded, I save the file information in the model I want to send to the server (the output of the file upload component is attached). Now my question is how should I save the file on the server with this information? Files are sent in different formats (png, jpg, pdf, ...) and I am looking for a solution to store these files on the server.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `originFileObj`, get it and then append it to FormData, and afterward send it by using axios or fetch. There is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/41r2n?file=/index.js) in the antd documentation about it